# My css works on my html pages but not on my php pages

Tags: php, html, css

I created a project description page for my portfolio. Initially, I wanted to create an html page for each of my projects but I discovered that I didn't need to do it with PHP and a database. So I had made a template for my pages in html and css. The css worked perfectly. I redid my html page to integrate php. Except that now the css only works halfway!! Some elements are styled (like the view-button) but most of the elements are not (like the text)...
I do not understand why... Can you help me please ?

**Here is my basic HTML code (with which the css worked perfectly) :**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Punkode</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c1644d52e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='stars'></div>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="home">ACCUEIL</a>
      <!-- INTRODUCTION -->
      <div class="intro" >
        <div class="intro-container" style="background: url(img/projets/punkode_photo.png);background-size:cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;">
          <div class="project-name">
            <h1 class="highlight"> PUNKODE </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- PROJECTS -->
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="laptop">
            <img src="./img/laptop.png" draggable="false" alt="" />
            <div class="holo"></div>
            <div class="laptopScreen">
              <img src="./img/projets/screen_punkode.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" class="laptopApp" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="projectDetail">
            <h1 class="projectTitle">Projet</h1>
            <p class="projectDesc">
                Ardeo, mihi credite, Patres conscripti (id quod vosmet de me existimatis et facitis ipsi) incredibili quodam amore patriae, qui me amor et subvenire olim impendentibus periculis maximis cum dimicatione capitis, et rursum, cum omnia tela undique esse intenta in patriam viderem, subire coegit atque excipere unum pro universis. 
            </p>
            <button class="view-button">Voir</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="project">
          <div class="chibi">
            <img src="./img/projets/chibi_punkode.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="projectDetail">
            <h1 class="projectTitle">Mon rôle</h1>
            <p class="projectDesc">
                Hic me meus in rem publicam animus pristinus ac perennis cum C. Caesare reducit, reconciliat, restituit in gratiam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
</body>
```

**And here is my code with php which directly retrieves the elements in a table of my database :**

```
<?php
// Inclure le fichier de configuration de la base de données
require_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    try {
        // Récupérer l'ID de la trace depuis l'URL
        $traceId = $_GET['id'];

        // Récupérer les détails de la trace depuis la base de données
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM trace WHERE immatriculation = :id";
        $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $traceId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $trace = $stmt->fetch();

        // Vérifier si une trace correspondante a été trouvée
        if ($trace) {
            // Afficher les détails de la trace
            ?>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title><?php echo $trace['nom_trace']; ?></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
                <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c1644d52e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div class='stars'></div>
                <div class="container">
                  <a href="index.html" class="home">ACCUEIL</a>
                  <!-- INTRODUCTION -->
                  <div class="intro" >
                    <div class="intro-container" style="background: url('<?php echo $trace['image_couverture']; ?>');background-size:cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;">
                      <div class="project-name">
                        <h1 class="highlight"> <?php echo $trace['nom_trace']; ?> </h1>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- PROJECTS -->
                  <div class="projects">
                    <div class="project">
                      <div class="laptop">
                        <img src="./img/laptop.png" draggable="false" alt="" />
                        <div class="holo"></div>
                        <div class="laptopScreen">
                          <img src="<?php echo $trace['image_description']; ?>" draggable="false" alt="" class="laptopApp" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="projectDetail">
                        <h1 class="projectTitle">Projet</h1>
                        <p class="projectDesc">
                          <?php echo $trace['description_projet']; ?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $trace['lien_trace']; ?>" class="view-button">Voir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="project">
                      <div class="chibi">
                        <img src="./img/projets/chibi_punkode.png" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="projectDetail">
                        <h1 class="projectTitle">Mon rôle</h1>
                        <p class="projectDesc">
                            <?php echo $trace['description_role']; ?>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="footer">
                    <div class="row">
                      <p> 2023</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <script src="trois.js"></script>
              </body>
            </html>
            <?php
        } else {
            // Aucune trace correspondante trouvée
            echo 'Trace introuvable.';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'exécution de la requête : " . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // ID de la trace non fourni dans l'URL
    echo 'ID de trace non spécifié.';
}
?>
```

**And here is a snippet of my CSS file :**

```
  .projects {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30vh;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  
  .project {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 100px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .project:first-child {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  
  .chibi {
    flex: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .chibi img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .projectDetail {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    padding:0 100px;
  }
  .strong {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(114, 0, 255), rgb(242, 0, 255));
    padding: 2px 6px;
  }
  
  .projectTitle {
    font-size: 7vw;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(114, 0, 255), 0 0 25px rgb(114, 0, 255);
    animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
  }
  .projectDesc {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #dedede;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  .view-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
 }
 .view-button:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
  .view-button:hover::before {
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 140%;
    width: 120%;
    left: -10%;
    top: -20%
     }
```

Thank you so much !

Comment: The browser doesn't know or care how the HTML was created, whether from a static HTML or from PHP. If you generate the same HTML, the CSS should work.

Comment: What debugging have you done? You should be able to use the Elements tab of Developer Tools to see which styles are being applied to each element. Can you be specific about a particular element and what part of its style you're not seeing?

Comment: Is the CSS asset loaded? I'd also look closely at the page source. Or maybe you have missed an open or close tag.  Also, consider exploring this syntax for conditionals in this scenario: `<?php if($condition): ?> I'm HTML <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I see the src is a little ambiguous. Maybe try `href="/style.css"`?

Comment: @ficuscr If some of the styles are working, it must be loading the CSS file.

Comment: @Barmar hey! probably. Or it's just default styles being misinterpreted. Noting the `./img/` stuff...

Comment: I just checked and the style only applies to my view-button. And not all the styling, for example the button is supposed to be animated but the animation doesn't work....
Other elements on my page are not styled at all in the Elements tab of Developer Tools

Comment: OK, I just solved my problem!
I just changed the name of my style.css file and everything works... Maybe the name was too ambiguous! Thanks a lot for your help :)